# Finding account number in string

Tags: python

Good day I have a script that searches messages to decipher an account number and later on in the script it will remove and spaces or dashes in the script.

However I have come accross a scenario where it leaves out a single digit at the end of the string as follows;

```
Account number: 10 11 837 451 4
```

Where it this case it does not find the 4 at the end

Here is the part of the code responsible for finding the number

```
search = re.findall("[0-9]{8,11}|\d+[-\s]?\d+[-\s]?\d+[-\s]?\d+[-\s]?", test)
```

Comment: Do you have more examples of strings to match against ?

Comment: Hint: you have exactly 4 `\d+`, but you have five groups of numbers.

Comment: Do you understand the regex you use ? Because if so you'll the small modification to apply

Comment: Thanks @Robᵩ cant believe I didnt pick that up

Comment: Depending on the input strings you are searching and how clean they are, it might be cleaner to match the pattern `r"\d+[-\d\s]*\d"`

Comment: If you would try `[0-9]{8,11}|\d+[-\s]?` then also it will match everything but according to above regex are you sure it will get only 8-11 digit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct code:
The issue from what I understand from the comments is that because there was an extra group of numbers all I needed to do was ad an extra;
"d+[-\s]?"

First solution:
This solution will only work for 5 groups of numbers

```
search = re.findall("[0-9]{8,11}|\d+[-\s]?\d+[-\s]?\d+[-\s]?\d+[-\s]?\d+[-\s]?", test)
```

Second solution:
This solution will work for a many groups of numbers

```
search = re.findall(r"\d+[-\d\s]*\d", test)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer with an explanation what the problem was and why / how this regex fixes it. That way others with similar problems could learn from your answer.